# Play Buttons of SoundManager2 are disabled in Ajax o JS

Tags: views, ajax

I have a views that call a content type with soundmanager fields (360 style) with pager.

On the first page show 3 soundmanager fields and play ok, but in the second page by ajax the no longer played in the input play btn.

In the second page the input play not function.

I tested with 3 options:
Infinite scroll module.
Custom js code for the scroll in the same page.
Views Module load more.

In all feel the same, in the second page loaded in ajax or js buttons play of SoundManager are disabled.

appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Add below script in Ajax call

```
<script>
soundManager.reboot();
</script>
```

Comment: I wonder why they first downvoted this answer meanwhile it is a good answer and I have just tried it and it worked. You don't even need to add this to the ajax call, you just have to add it to the page that receives the ajax call and it works